# How to maintain several collections where an object can only exist in one?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a class and an enum that looks something like this

```
class Container{
    static int next_id = 0; 
    final int id = next_id++;
    State state = State.one;
}

enum State{
    one, two, three, four, five;
}
```

I want to maintain several collections of Container but maintain that for any instance of Container, it is only present in one collection. The collections need to be thread safe, and I cannot store the Container directly in a hash based collection, as its hash will change based on its current state.

--edit--

To further clarify, the goal of this is to be able to retrieve all Containers that are in a given state, without having to inspect every single container's state as there are several thousand containers.

Comment: What operations do you want to perform on the collections?  Do you want to be able to move Containers between them, or simply guarantee that if you try to add a Container to a collection it will fail if the Container is already in another collection?

Comment: Move containers into their correct collection when their state changes. Ideally I would like to just add it to the correct collection and it would cease to be in the prior collection upon doing so.

Comment: Isn't any field that won't change while the `Container` instance is alive?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't understand what you mean, are you talking about its ID not changing?

Comment: Sorry, I was to meant field. Comment updated.

Comment: the id field should have been marked as final. So that one will not change while the container is alive.

Comment: You say "its hash will change based on its current state" > have you overriden `hashCode()`?

Comment: Yes, it has its own hashCode and equals method. I couldn't think of an easy way to draw it up in this mock object as there are many other fields in the real object that the hash and equals take into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to ensure that without writing some code yourself, as maintaining consistency, i.e. a Container belonging to exactly one collection depending on its state, requires not only the collections' but also the members' support.

Disregarding that the target language is java, I would probably suggest linked lists, something like this:

```
class Container{
    static int next_id = 0; 
    final int id = next_id++;
    final Node<Container> node;
    State state;

    public Container() {
        node = new Node<>(this);
        setState(State.one);
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        if(this.state != null) node.unlink();
        this.state = state;
        if(this.state != null) this.state.containers.add(node);
    }
}

enum State{
    one, two, three, four, five;
    final List<Container> containers = ...;
}
```

This code only works efficiently because, knowing the node, an element can be unlinked from the linked list in O(1). (add is of course O(1) as well). Java's default linked list does not expose nodes, so every access requires a linear search, which is inefficient.

In the light of this, the next best thing is using a hash based approach. Some of the code can still remain:

- setting the state is somewhat complex, so the logic should be put in a setter, not in the client doing `container.state = ...`
- as long as the collections of containers are application wide (hint: in a managed environment, like an application server, they hardly are!), they can be maintained directly by the enum. otherwise, give the containers some kind of `Context` that holds an `EnumMap<State, Map<Integer, Container>>` or similar.

The result:

```
class Container{
    static int next_id = 0; 
    final int id = next_id++;
    State state;

    public Container() {
        setState(State.one);
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        if(this.state != null) this.state.containers.remove(id);
        this.state = state;
        if(this.state != null) this.state.containers.put(id, node);
    }
}

enum State{
    one, two, three, four, five;
    final Map<Integer, Container> containers = new HashMap<>();
}
```

by using the id as the key, you don't have to worry about your own `hashCode` and `equals` implementations.

---

Regarding visibility: You really, really want to make a bunch of this private - or default (I'm looking at the maps in `State`) at the very least.

Regarding thread safety: I don't want to lean out of the window here (I'm no expert), but using `ConcurrentHashMap`s will probably do much of what you need. Also, synchronize `setState`. If you don't, two concurrent updates could insert the container into two maps. Finally, `final int id = next_id++;` is not thread safe to my knowledge, because `++` is not atomic. you could use `AtomicInteger` here.

Comment: Accepting this. You even preemptively addressed the issue of it not being application wide. The only complication is needing to modify the Containers setState method, but that may be unavoidable.

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to test it yet, but The concurrent Hash Map will most likely work. and the ID generation isn't actually done the way its written, that was just to illustrate that the id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `hashCode()` method to not factor in its `State state` so the hash would remain the same no matter the content of the `state` variable.

Even better, because your `Container`s id variable is what you are sorting by, and there exists only one `Container` per id, you could just do:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.id;
}
```

If you want the hashCodes to not be linear, you could just XOR it against some number, and it will still be guaranteed unique per `id`

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (2807 ^ this.id);
}
```

Comment: I believe the state is needed in the hash, as it is needed in the .equals method.

Comment: @Lexxicon Not true. A (useless) hash could just `return 42;` and not break the hash code contract. The important thing is that when two objects are equal, they have the same hashcode value.

Comment: Since `id` will be marked as `final` (check comment from OP), there's no need to use `Container` hashcode. Let the JDK to handle this by using `Integer#hashCode` (which ends returning the current `int` value)

Comment: How does this answer (and the others answers) address the enforcement of "only in one container" rule?

Comment: @Duncan ah, it was always explained and shown to me as anything thats a part of the equals needs to be in the hash as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get the effect that you have described (add it to the proper collection on state change and have it automatically disappear from the prior collection) by using `HashMap`for your collections. I say 'probably' because there may be other, unstated, requirements.

As you note, when you update the `state`, the hashcode value will change. This means you will no longer be able to retrieve it from the `HashMap` that has had the prior state when it was `put`, and it effectively disappears from the prior `HashMap`. Whenever you update `state` you should `put` it in the `HashMap` relevant for the new `state`.

Your unit test would call the "update state" method with various state changes and validate that when you `get` from each collection that it is found in only one collection and it is the right one.

Comment: That is a clever idea, but has two issues. The first is that I need to use the contents of the collections, so I'm not calling .get(key) I'm using the valueSet, which will have all prior answers in it. The second, which is related to the first, is that the map retains the container indefinitely and based on the large number of containers I'm working with would cause massive memory overhead.

Comment: @Lexxicon and that's easily solved by using flyweight pattern.

Comment: And thus the caveat about "unstated requirements."